# Protractor - Exception of Cannot read property 'headerPrinter' of undefined appears after every run

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I really don't know what is the reason for this exception and what are the side effects of it.
But It appears every time even all test cases are passed.
Please help to figure out how to solve this -

```
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'headerPrinter' of undefined
    at printHeader (C:\automation\tests\node_modules\protractor-console\dist\protractor-console.js:81:8)
    at C:\automation\tests\node_modules\protractor-console\dist\protractor-console.js:56:19
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

[image]

*Protractor conf:*

```
//-=-=-=- Packages -=-=-=-

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var util = require('util');
var Imap = require('imap'),
    inspect = require('util').inspect;
var MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser;
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream('c:\\automation\\tests\\' + '/emailResponses.log', {flags : 'w'});
// var log_exceptions = fs.createWriteStream('c:\\automation\\tests\\' + '/exceptions.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;

//-=-=-=- Helpers -=-=-=-

    captureScreen = function(name){
        browser.driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data){
            var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
            return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
                var fname = name + "-" + cap.caps_.browserName + ".png";
                    fs.writeFile(fname, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
                        if(err) console.log(err);
                });
            });
        });
    }

  waitPageToLoad = function(){
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60000); 
  }

  getLastEmail = function() {
      var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
      console.log("Waiting for an email...");

      mailListener.on("mail", function(mail){
          deferred.fulfill(mail);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    };


// -=-=- Testing configuration -=-=-

exports.config = {

  chromeDriver: 'npm/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
  chromeOnly: false,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['c:\\automation\\tests\\frontageSanity.js'],

plugins: [{
    package: 'C:\\automation\\tests\\node_modules\\protractor-console',
    logLevels: ['severe', 'warning']
  }],

  // directConnect: true,

  multiCapabilities: [{
  // 'browserName': 'firefox',
  //     'cli': {
  //     'args': ['webdriver.firefox.useExisting=default', '-jsconsole', '-jsdebugger']
// }}, 
// }

 // {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    args: ['--no-sandbox','--test-type','--memory-metrics','--console','--crash-on-failure'],
    // '--load-extension=' + 'C:\\Users\\idan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj\\1.2.4_0'
    prefs: {
      download: {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'directory_upgrade': true,
          'default_directory': 'C:\\automation\\tests\\downloaded\\'
                }
            }
        } 
    // },

  // {
      // 'browserName': 'internet explorer',
      // 'platform': 'ANY',
      // 'version': '12'
    }],

  framework: "jasmine",

  allScriptsTimeout: 90000,

  getPageTimeout: 90000,


// -=-=- Pre-Conditions & Tools configurations -=-=- 

  onPrepare: function() {

    //-=-=-=- HTML Reporter -=-=-=-
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'C:\\automation\\tests\\HtmlReporter\\',
         // takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
         docTitle: 'vCita - Sanity testing report',
         docName: 'Test_Report.html',
         cssOverrideFile: 'htmlReporter_css.css'
      }));

   browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
      browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
    });

    // -=-=-=- Email Listener - here goes your email connection configuration -=-=-=-
    var mailListener = new MailListener({
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        host: "imap.gmail.com",
        port: 993, // imap port 
        tls: true,
        tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
        mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor 
        // searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", "FLAGGED"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved 
        markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time 
        fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`, 
        // mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib. 
        // attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory 
        // attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments 
    });

      mailListener.start();

      mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
        console.log("imapConnected");
      });

      mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
        console.log("imapDisconnected");
      });

      mailListener.on("mail", function(){
        // console.log("GO IT!");
      });

      mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
      // do something with mail object including attachments
        console.log("emailParsed", mail)
        // mail processing code goes here
        log_file.write(util.format(mail));
        log_stdout.write(util.format(mail));
      });

      global.mailListener = mailListener;
}, 

// onCleanUp: function () {
//     mailListener.stop();
// }, 

 // -=-=- Node JS Settings -=-=-

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
      onComplete: function () {
      mailListener.stop();
    },
      // If true, display spec names.
      isVerbose: true,
      // If true, print colors to the terminal.
      showColors: true,
      // If true, include stack traces in failures.
      includeStackTrace: true,
      // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 9999999
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you show your protractor config? In particular, the plugins and specs sections most importantly.

Comment: Sure, I've added the packages from my conf file @alecxe

Comment: Nono, I mean post your protractor config contents..

Comment: Got you, done! @alecxe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you needed to install and use is called [`protractor-console-plugin`](https://github.com/angular/protractor-console-plugin), not `protractor-console`.